Civievent - Parent registers multiple children
I currently want to let parents register multiple children for an event. What I have right now is a parent registers for an event and the child information goes in as a custom field that accepts multiple values. This works great for registering a single child or registering multiple children by filling out the form, submitting the form, and then doing it all again. However, I want to take advantage of being able to register additional participants in the same form. However, when I do that, since the parent is technically the attendee, the form complains that the first and last name of a participant must be different - even though it works fine when submitting the form multiple times.
I have multiple participants enabled, using the unsupervised deduping rule, and letting the user use the same email.
Is there a better way to handle this? I am on WordPress so webform won't work here.
Thank you!

We used CiviCRM: Group Event Participant Registration  extension to achieve this.
